# rails using touch in polymorphism leads to bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

my child model:

```
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    belongs_to :dedicated_to, polymorphic: true , touch: true
```

my parent model:

```
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
has_many :dedications, as: :dedicated_to
```

and now see this:

```
irb(main):050:0> Parent.find("523aab9f8c1ec39417000242").dedications.first.touch
=> true
irb(main):050:0> a = Parent.find("523aab9f8c1ec39417000242").dedications.first.dedicated_to
irb(main):050:0> b = Parent.find("523aab9f8c1ec39417000242")
irb(main):050:0> a == b
=> true
irb(main):050:0> a.updated_at
=> Sat, 21 Sep 2013 19:45:08 UTC +00:00
irb(main):050:0> b.updated_at
=> Sun, 22 Sep 2013 15:54:55 UTC +00:00
```

as you see , we have an unexpected paradox here. a is updated but b is not. and even it says that a = b !

Comment: report the bug att at https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu how do you know whether this is caused by mongoid or not?

Comment: Because that's a mongoid feature.

Comment: try `a.reload` before getting its update attribute.In Rails `==` returns true if the compared objects have same id and are of the same type but they can different attributes.